# How to set a filepath in VBA that will vary based on the month?

Tags: vba, excel, save

I'm having an issue. Currently I have a couple vb modules working off one another that when executed will increment a drop down list, save a version of each option on the drop down list, and print out a copy as well.

Right now I'm using this filepath.

```
Sub G5()
    'Update 20141112
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Path = "C:\Users\MY.Name\Documents\Testing\" & _
            Range("G5") & "\" 
    filename = Range("G5")
    If ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value = "" Then End
    If ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value = "NAMES" Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & "-" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```

So cell G5 contains the name (Last, First) of the person whose voucher this is. Each name is data validated and is identical to the name of their individual folder. Currently the script will save to their folder, but within those folders are 12 sub folders, one for each month. Is there any way for me to get the files to save into the correct month folder?

Cell I10 is the only cell that mentions the month by name, but in the format of "June Transit Reimbursement"

Any help would be appreciated. The script above runs in conjunction with two others, and although its doing 95% of what I need it to do, if I can get past this final hurdle the process will be 100% automated.

I'm trying to read through Like Operators and Option Compare Statements, but I'm struggling, and after reading so many posts here am hoping someone can help

Comment: Sure! How come you don't just add that third variable in there? `Path = "C:\Users\MY.Name\Documents\Testing\" & Range("G5") & "\" & theMonth & "\"`? (Am I missing something?)  What's determining which month is the "correct" month? Is it the current month we're in?

Comment: @BruceWayne hey bruce, unfortunately we have some vouchers that come through a bit lagged so even though this month should be seeing vouchers for June, we get late ones from any time period in the previous 90 days. It needs to be dynamic (maybe?) and able to identify which month is mentioned in cell i10 or at least reflect the same month found there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the month by taking the first word from I10 and then put it in the file path assuming your folders use the same name formats that show up in I10.

```
parts = Split(Range("I10"), " ")
theMonth = parts(0) & " " & parts(1)
Path = "C:\Users\MY.Name\Documents\Testing\" & Range("G5") & "\" & theMonth & "\"
```

Updated to use first 2 words from cell using Mat's Mugs comments.

Comment: This is really close to working! Is it possible to take the first two words from i10 instead of just the first one? That is how the naming conventions would need to line up

Comment: @creddit extract a variable to hold the array that the `Split` function gives you - say `parts`, and then concatenate `theMonth = parts(0) & " " & parts(1)`

Comment: @Mat'sMug hey Mat's Mug, I'm reaally really new to all this. So far I would consider any of my projects a greater mixture of luck, context clues and copying and pasting than programming skills. Could you go into some specifics on how to create a variable to hold the array? Sorry if I sound like a newbie, but I am!

Comment: `Dim parts As Variant` to declare an explicit variant, then `parts = Split(Range("I10"), " ")` to split the content of `I10` at every whitespace, giving you an array that you assign to `parts`. Then `parts(0) & " " & parts(1)` concatenates the first two "parts" into a string, which you can assign to `theMonth` variable.